# Android Application Project not showing under dropdown

Tags: android, eclipse

I was running Eclipse 4.2 from Google's ADT bundle and it was not starting properly so I decided to install Eclipse 4.3, the SDK and the ADT plugin separately, instead of using the ADT Bundle.

Now, when I was using Google's ADT bundle, in the dropdown menu for "File - New", you would see "Android Application Project". In my new install, Eclipse 4.3, it is nowhere to be found. You can only see it if you click on "Other" and then you will have to search for it under the "Android" folder.

Do you know how I can get it back in the dropdown, instead of having to find it every time under "Other"?
[image]

Comment: Oh yeah! I've just changed from Indigo to Kepler and now you come to mention it, I have to go to the 'other' option to start an Android project. I installed the separate parts too, as I already had the SDK.

Comment: And you are sure that you have appropriately linked your Android SDK?

Comment: I'm sure I have... Whenever I click on new Android Application Project, it generates a new activity template with generic code, like onCreate etc,. Im guessing that won't happen if the SDK wasn't linked properly? I also click on Android SDK Manager in Eclipse and it shows me what I have installed/not installed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to `Window -> Customize Perspective -> Menu visibility -> File -> New` and check "Android Application Project" option:

[image: Eclipse: Customize Perspective]

Answer (score 2):

This usually happens when you don't select any android SDK in "Preferences > Android". Some wired cases if you set the path also this problem may occurs. So solution to overcome it is,You just have to reset the perspective in eclipse, Windows > Reset Perspective.

Hope this is still helpful.